# Azure Mobile Services offline data - problems with mapping and initialization

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am using the Mobile Services data offline mode in Xamarin and have a couple of issues.

First and foremost, I am not sure how my object mapping should be set up for my data classes. Here is a simple example of one of my data classes named "Section":

```
public class Section : BaseModel
    {
        private SurveyType _SurveyType;
        public SurveyType SurveyType {
            get { return _SurveyType; }
            set {
                if (value.Equals (_SurveyType))
                    return;
                _SurveyType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged ();
            }
        }

        private string _Name;
        public string Name {
            get { return _Name; }
            set {
                if (value.Equals (_Name, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    return;
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged ();
            }
        }

        private int _SortOrder;
        public int SortOrder {
            get { return _SortOrder; }
            set {
                if (value.Equals (_SortOrder))
                    return;
                _SortOrder = value;
                OnPropertyChanged ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, if you notice, the BaseModel class is implemented. This simply defines the Id property of type string. The problem here is that the "SurveyType" column refers to another class. What I was hoping would happen is that the Id of the SurveyType class would be inserted into the Sections table on save. What happens instead is that I receive an error from the MobileServices service that it cannot insert a data type of "object" into the database.

Is there a better way to map my data relationships, or am I stuck storing just the Id of each referenced class?

My second issue is that many times, when I call the following method on a new database, I get an error about the table not being defined:

```
store.DefineTable<Section> ();
```

In this case, "store" is an instance of  MobileServiceSQLiteStore.
From what I've seen, this is the proper method to call in order to define the table in the offline/online database in order to perform CRUD operations against it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Related entities can now be saved as JSON in same table in a column. You also have the option to split the object at the store level and save it in separate table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about question # 2 but for what concerns mapping complex types (#1) I believe this post by Carlos Figueroa can answer it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/08/23/complex-types-and-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Alberto

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.